# How to remove 'update-alternatives' links on Linux

Tags: linux, centos, debian, symbolic-link

Sorry for asking this, but I cannot resolve such a simple issue for a few hours:

I made a typo mistake in

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblapack.so libRblapack.so /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblapack_native.so 100
```

It should be libRlapack.so instead of libRblapack. The problem is that if issue a correct command line, i.e.

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so libRlapack.so /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack_native.so 100
```

it returns an error:

> the primary link for libRlapack.so must be
>   /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblapack.so

I tried

```
update-alternatives --remove libRblapack.so /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblapack.so
```

but it doesn't work - returns the same error when entering a correct command.

How can I get it fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would try cleaning it up manually. I've never done this so make sure you backup beforehand.

- Remove the link from /etc/alternatives
- Remove the relevant file from the admin directory

  - /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/ on ubuntu (debian may be the same but check the man pages under the FILES section)
  - /var/lib/alternatives/ on CentOS 6&7

Comment: Thanks! it worked - I have just edited the link file in /var/lib/alternatives/

Answer (score 9):

Removing them manually resulted in `... is already managed by ...` error in my case. Aside from that, the manual removal also didn't scale, as i've had added multiple multiple alternatives for the centralized symlink. It's just a mess.

When it comes to either `update-alternatives` or `alternatives`, they both provide the `--remove` and `--remove-all` flags. As for the former flag, it only removes one single alternative of the link group. For example

```
$ update-alternatives --list python3
/usr/bin/python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.9

$ sudo update-alternatives --remove python3 /usr/bin/python3.9

$ update-alternatives --list python3
/usr/bin/python3.8
```

The form of the `--remove` flag goes by
`update-alternatives --remove symlink-generic-name /path/to/one/executable/alternative`

However, if you want to outright erase the generic name with all of its associated alternatives all at once, then `--remove-all` is the way to go.

```
$ update-alternatives --list python3
/usr/bin/python3.8
/usr/bin/python3.9

$ sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python3

$ update-alternatives --list python3
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3

$ update-alternatives --query python3
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3
```

Comment: BEWARE, while using `--remove-all`, will remove the preinstalled version of that software which may be a required component of your OS.

Example: Python, which is required for some operating systems like Ubuntu using remove -all with python on Ubuntu will break the OS